# formatting following melt (wide to long)

Tags: r, reshape, formattable

I have a dataframe in wide format where I have applied Comma/percentage formatting based on columns. So some columns are comma separated and some are percentages.

When I use melt to get it in to a long format, I lose the formatting. Does anyone know how I can retain the formatting or reformat each row based on columns?

**Wide:**

```
id event balance change
1  up      100.00   2.0%
2  down  1,000.00   0.4%
3  up    1,000.00   1.2%
4  down  2,000.00   3.0%
```

**Long:**

```
id event metric  value
1  up    balance 100
2  up    change  0.02
3  down  balance 1000
4  down  change  0.004
5  up    balance 1000
6  up    change  0.012
7  down  balance 2000
8  down  change  0.03
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] ... **then edit your question!**

Comment: Perhaps you need `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);df1 %>% mutate_at(3:4, funs(as.numeric(sub("[,%]", "", .)))) %>% mutate(change = change/100) %>% gather(metric, value, balance:change) %>% arrange(id)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution akrun! works great.